# KeyError: 'Records' while trying to read CSV file from S3 bucket - Lambda trigger

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following lambda function code for simply printing out the column name of CSV file from S3 bucket.

```
import json
import boto3
import csv

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print(event)
    
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    csv_file = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=csv_file)
    lines = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split()
    results = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(lines):
        results.append(row.name())
    print(results)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

However, I am getting the following error while testing:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'Records'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 10, in lambda_handler
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
```

Not sure where I am going wrong! Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

After updating "Test" event manually, I am getting this error;

```
Test Event Name
TestEvent2

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 13, in lambda_handler\n    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=csv_file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 705, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

I have full access to my S3 bucket. Also, while printing the event its showing correct object name, s3 bucket name, records[] etc.

Comment: What exactly is the output of `print(event)`?

Comment: {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}

Comment: Event type is : "ObjectCreated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you are using `Test` in AWS console. In that case some default `event` is provided. For your code you have to provide valid S3 event for your use-case. The S3 event structure is given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html) so you have to setup your `Test` to use valid `event` structure.

Alternatively, you can use AWS console provided events:

[image]

Comment: Event type is : "ObjectCreated"

Comment: How can I update same trigger event for my s3 bucket?

Comment: @adey27 You update it manually in test event console.

Comment: I just did, now I am getting different error. updated my question

Comment: @adey27 If you have new error, new question should be asked.

Comment: i've asked my ques in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70750672/reading-csv-file-from-s3-using-lambda-function-getobject-operation-access-denie/70750803#70750803